# Exponential: What's the probability John will wait more than 1 hour for his 4 friends?

Tags: probability, statistics

I was studying for statistics exam and I'm having a hard time solving this problem:

John is never late and his friends are usually 20 minutes late (exponencial distribuition).

John invited one of his friends for lunch, what's the probability he will wait less than 30 minutes?

This one was easily solved by using the [comulative distribuition function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BF4wZ.png)

If John invites his four friends, what's the probability he will have to wait more than 10 minutes alone?

This one was solved in a similar fashion to the above one, calculating the probability for one friend and then taking the power of four of the result.

What's the probability John will have to wait more than 1 hour for everyone to be on the spot?

This is the one I'm having issues with. I've tried taking the probability of waiting more than 60 minutes for one of them as I did with the problem above, however, since it's for all four friends, only the last one matters and they can either reach all after 60 minutes, only one after 60 minutes, two of them, etc.

**Edit for clarity:** Basically at least one of his friends (the last one to arrive) has to arrive after 60 minutes, they can all be an hour late but it can also happen that only one is that late, and so on.

Appreciate any answer or feedback.

Comment: One statistics exam or four of them?  Can you find the chance that one friend is at least an hour late?  Now you want the chance that at least one is an hour late, which calls for inclusion-exclusion.

Comment: @saulspatz gave a bit more context to hopefully don't seem like I'm just asking without trying.

Comment: @RossMillikan fixed typo, and yes as you can see on the edit I can find for just one of them, the problem is combining all of the possibilities together

Comment: Can you do it for two friends?  Look again at what Ross Millikan said about inclusion-exclusion.

Comment: @saulspatz the idea would be to calculate (for friends A and B) the three situations:
A before than 1 hour and B after 1 hour, B before than 1 hour and A after 1 hour and for A and B both come after 1 hour? Or would that be complicating it too much?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last one is just the same as the next to last.  For the last one, to wait less than one hour, compute the chance one friend is there within one hour.  Now you need them all there within one hour, so raise it to the fourth power. That gives the chance he does not wait more than one hour, so subtract from $1$.

Comment: It's not within one hour, it's wait MORE than one hour for all to be there, that is, at least the last one has to arrive after one hour.

Comment: I left a couple bits out, which I have now added.  Here it is easier to compute the chance he waits less than an hour and subtract from $1$

Comment: Yes that's what I thought, don't know how I didn't think of that before, thanks!